# Multiple records not available when creating .CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

@orders should have multiple orders yet when using a respond_to to create an CSV, I only have one order record available in my cvs.erb file. Here's the code.

**reports_controller.rb**

```
   def orders
         params[:q] = {} unless params[:q]

        if params[:q][:completed_at_gt].blank?
          params[:q][:completed_at_gt] = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month
        else
          params[:q][:completed_at_gt] = Time.zone.parse(params[:q][:completed_at_gt]).beginning_of_day rescue Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month
        end

        if params[:q] && !params[:q][:completed_at_lt].blank?
          params[:q][:completed_at_lt] = Time.zone.parse(params[:q][:completed_at_lt]).end_of_day rescue ""
        end

        params[:q][:s] ||= "completed_at desc"

        @search = Order.complete.ransack(params[:q])
        @orders = @search.result

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.csv do
                headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"Order-List\"#{Date.today}"
                headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'
            end 
        end
    end
```

**order_items.csv.erb**

```
<%- headers = ['Order Number', 'User', 'Item Total', 'Discount Value', 'Sales Total', 'Promotions'] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line headers %>
<%- @orders.each do |order| -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line([order.number, order.email, order.item_total, order.promo_total, order.total]) %>
<%- end -%>
```

**order_items.html.erb**

```
 <%= search_form_for @search, :url =>      spree.order_items_admin_reports_path  do |s| %>
  <div class="form-group date-range-filter">
     <%= label_tag nil, Spree.t(:date_range) %>
   <div class="date-range-filter row">
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <%= s.text_field :completed_at_gt, :class => 'datepicker datepicker-from form-control', :value => datepicker_field_value(params[:q][:completed_at_gt]) %>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
     <%= s.text_field :completed_at_lt, :class => 'datepicker datepicker-to form-control', :value => datepicker_field_value(params[:q][:completed_at_lt]) %>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

 <div class="form-actions">
   <%= button Spree.t(:search), 'search' %>
 </div>

 <%= link_to "Export CSV", order_items_admin_reports_path(format: 'csv', :params[:q] => params[:q]), {:style => 'margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px;', :class => "btn btn-primary btn-success"} %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Curious if you have output/debugged the controller action - something like `puts @orders.inspect` before the `respond_to` block - to ensure that `@orders` is populated with more than a single record?

Comment: Yah, so multiple orders exist in @orders before the repond_to block.

Comment: You're not giving us enough info here.  log out what `@orders` looks like before the block and in the erb

Comment: My link_to isn't passing any of the required params to get the orders.

Comment: How would I be able to submit this exact form but format it as a csv?